# extract numerals from a line in file using perl

Tags: perl, split

Suppose I have the following lines in a file:

```
set gate report abc 28 -ext
set gate report xyz 29 -ext
set gate report hello 35 -ext
```

I want to extract the numerals 28, 29 and so on from the lines and put them into a variable.
Supposing this file has 100 similar lines, how can I extract the numerals?
Can I use split in some manner for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) to capture the numbers and store them in an array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @nums;
while (<DATA>) {
    push @nums, $1 if /(\d+)/;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@nums);

__DATA__
set gate report abc 28 -ext
set gate report xyz 29 -ext
set gate report hello 35 -ext
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '28',
          '29',
          '35'
        ];
```

I think regex is a more appropriate tool than `split` in this case.

[Basics of reading a file.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Files-and-I/O)